# Autodesk forge file translation to svf not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am currently following the prepare the file for viewer tutorial on autodesk forge. This is the link:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/
Rather than making the requests using cURL, I have made javascript code using jquery ajax to make the requests. I have made each request a function, with a button to trigger each request, as the code shows below. Currently, each request works fine except for the translate to svf request. When I attempt to make that request and check the status of my request the following message is printed:

```
    {
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cHJvamVjdGZpbGVzMTIzNC9fTUMtMTQwMDYlMjBGT0xERVIlMjBBU1NZJTIwLSUyMEhTQ0YtMTIuaWFtLmR3Zg",
"derivatives": [{
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "name": "_MC-14006 FOLDER ASSY - HSCF-12.iam.dwf",
    "progress": "complete",
    "messages": [{
        "type": "error",
        "code": "DWF2D-Not_A_DWF_Error",
        "message": "Unable to open, not a DWF/DWFx file."
    }, {
        "type": "error",
        "message": "Extractor error code -11",
        "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
    }],
    "outputType": "svf",
    "status": "failed"
}],
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"progress": "complete",
"type": "manifest",
"region": "US",
"version": "1.0",
"status": "failed"
```

Using postman, I can make the same request and everything will work fine. Then when I attempt to translate the file again, it will work as long as it's from the same bucket. I need files to be able to be uploaded and translated right away from the code, without having to translate it first in postman. I even attempted to copy the postman code for the translation request, but am getting the same error when the file is not already in my bucket. Below is my code for the simple webpage.

```
<html>
<title>Viewer</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/jstree.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #forgeViewer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 40px;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script>
//variable declaration
var access_token='';
const bucketKey = 'projectfiles123874';
const policyKey = 'transient';
var urn1 = '';
var urn2 = '';
var urn3 = '';
//var fileName = '_MC-14006 FOLDER ASSY - HSCF-12.iam.dwf';
var fileName = '';

if(access_token == ''){
getToken();
}

function getToken(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        data: 'client_id=lAOwCkVLo307t4fxWdEriDrPs1CAhdMl&client_secret=AhWJ5cIrm6Lh65AB&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read data:write bucket:read viewables:read bucket:create data:create',
        success:function(response){
            access_token=response.access_token;
            console.log(response);
            console.log(access_token);
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }) 
}

function createBucket(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets",
        headers:{
            "content-type": "application/json",
           // "x-ads-force":true,
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'bucketKey': bucketKey,
            'policyKey': policyKey
        }),

        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);

            //window.location.href = "http://team/www/upload.html";

        },
        error:function(error){
            if (error.response && error.response.status == 409){
                console.log("bucket alrready exists, skipping creation.");
            }
            else{
                console.log("failed to create new bucket.");
            }
        }
    })
}

function uploadFile(){

    $.ajax({
        method: 'PUT',
        url:"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/"+encodeURIComponent(bucketKey)+"/objects/"+encodeURIComponent(fileName)+"",
        data: 'C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\Desktop\DWGs\_MC-7251 CLOROX CARTON FORMER.iam.dwf',
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
           urn1 = response.objectId;
           console.log(urn1);
            urn2 = btoa(urn1);
            console.log(urn2);
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
}

function translateToSVF(){

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url:"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job",
        headers:{
            "content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        data:JSON.stringify({
            "input":{ "urn":urn2

            },
            "output":{ "destination":{
                "region": "us"
            },
                    "formats": [
                        {
                            "type": "svf",
                            "views": [
                                "2d",
                                "3d"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
            }
        }),
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            urn3=response.urn;
            console.log(urn3);
           // console.log(access_token);
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
/*    POSTMAN REQUEST CODE
    var settings = {
  "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "PF=5aKDLaxVErxdqJY5p40NQy",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({"input":{"urn":urn2,"rootFilename":fileName,"compressedUrn":false},"output":{"destination":{"region":"us"},"formats":[{"type":"svf","views":["2d","3d"]}]}}),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  urn3 = response.urn;
  console.log(urn3);
});
*/
}



function checkStatus(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/" + encodeURIComponent(urn3) + "/manifest",
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
}

    /*
    if(access_token == ''){
        getToken();
    }
    else if(urn1 == ''){
        uploadFile();
    }
    else translateToSVF();
    */
    function displayViewer(){
var viewer;
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'

    getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {

        var token = access_token;
        var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
        onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
    }
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

});

var documentId = 'urn:'+urn3;
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
}

}
/*
function check(){
    if (access_token='') getToken
}
*/

function processSelectedFiles(fileInput) {
  var files = fileInput.files;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   // alert("Filename " + files[i].name);
    fileName = files[i].name;
    console.log(fileName);
  }
}


</script>
<body><h1>Model Viewer</h1>
<p><button onclick="getToken()">Get Token</button></p>
<p><button onclick="createBucket()">Create Bucket</button></p>
<p><button onclick="uploadFile()">upload file</button></p>
<p><button onclick="translateToSVF()">Translate</button></p>
<p><button onclick="checkStatus()">Check Status</button></p>
<p><button onclick="displayViewer()">display Viewer</button></p>
<p><input type="file" id="input" onchange="processSelectedFiles(this)"></p>

<div id="forgeViewer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PUT` is not specifying a file name, just a folder, so probably the upload is corrupted. Also, you don't need to provide a `content-type`.

The file must be selected by the user, your browser app does not have access to the local folder structure. You can create an `input` file or `form`, then pass it to the `data` field

```
    method: 'PUT',
    url:"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/"+encodeURIComponent(bucketKey)+"/objects/"+encodeURIComponent(fileName)+"",
    data: theForm.theInput.files[0],
    headers:{
        Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
    },
```

You can verify your download via [SHA-1](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/checking-integrity-uploads-sha-1) signature or, easier, comparing the file size local and live (inside the bucket).

Comment: hi there Augusto, thanks for your help I have changed the data: to contain my filename as well. Now, when the translation starts I get a 0% progress status, however when I check the progress again, it fails once again. The same error code is left. Anything else I should try. If you could by chance run my code and see if you get the same error, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for all your help! @Augusto Goncalves

Comment: can you please update your question with your latest changes?

Comment: I have just updated my code with the small change, adding the filename to the end. I have also tried using just the filename, however both have not worked. The exact same requests work in postman. I have even tried copying the exact postman code without success. Could the problem be with me using xampp as my server. I am simply attempting to be able to upload one file at a time and simply display it in the viewer without using express. Thanks once again for your help! @Augusto Goncalves

Comment: This is what postman uses for the PUT request.                                  "data": "<file contents here>"

Comment: I have found that when I send my PUT request the response is as follows: bucketKey: "teamviewer"
contentType: "application/octet-stream"
location: "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/teamviewer/objects/_MC-14006FOLDERASSY-HSCF-12.iam.dwf"
objectId: "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:teamviewer/_MC-14006FOLDERASSY-HSCF-12.iam.dwf"
objectKey: "_MC-14006FOLDERASSY-HSCF-12.iam.dwf"
sha1: "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
size: 0                                                                           The problem is obviously that the size is zero. How can i fix this.

Comment: Now, I am getting sizes very small from 5-100 however when I run it using Postman I get sizes around 1 million, how can i achieve this

Comment: I've edited my function processSelectedFiles(fileInput) {                                                                      to include xfile = files [i] and then passed that to the data in jquery ajax. That seems to work now. Thanks again for all your help! @Augusto Goncalves